# Robolectric NPE when migrate from Android Studio 2.4 to 3.0

Tags: android, robolectric, android-studio-3.0

When migrating from Android Studio 2.4 to 3.0, most (perhaps All) of our test with Robolectric failing with the strange error below. We're using Robolectric 3.2.2.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:332)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:259)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.ResourceParser.load(ResourceParser.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResourceTableFactory.newResourceTable(ResourceTableFactory.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResourceMerger.buildResourceTable(ResourceMerger.java:22)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceTable(RobolectricTestRunner.java:499)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$600(RobolectricTestRunner.java:41)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:327)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadFile(DocumentLoader.java:39)
    at org.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.load(DocumentLoader.java:30)
    at org.robolectric.res.ResourceParser.load(ResourceParser.java:21)
... 24 more
```

Is it the support for Android Studio 3.0 is not ready yet for Robolectric?

**UPDATE**

The crash happens on Robolectric `DocumentLoader` class.

```
private void loadFile(FsFile dir, XmlLoader[] xmlLoaders) {
 if (!dir.exists()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("no such directory " + dir);
 }

 for (FsFile file : dir.listFiles(ENDS_WITH_XML)) {
  loadResourceXmlFile(file, xmlLoaders);
 }
}
```

When `dir.listFiles(ENDS_WITH_XML)`, it return Null. That's why it crash. Perhaps on the latest Android Studio, the resources are not generating XML?

**UPDATE**

Found this PR. Perhaps this would fix the issue, given when that's null, the `dir` is not a directory.

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/3158/files

**UPDATE**

Report the issue to Robolectric https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3216

Comment: What if you run it from console, does it fail?

Comment: Yes. same failure. Perhaps not Android Studio problem... more due to the new gradle?

Comment: Also you use AAPT2 (which is part of 3.0) then Roboelectric is not compatible with it too: set `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties` file

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Unfortunately, this will cause other errors in my dependent library, and my Instant App will stop working.

Comment: Cool! Make your own answer then!

Comment: No answer yet, as it is still not working.